# Installing an event handler module doesn't call the install() function (OpenCart 2.0)

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

The problem here is not somewhere in the event handler's code, I simply do not know how to actually implement the handlers. Is it done automatically? Is there a bit of code I have to add to some file, somewhere? The module itself doesn't appear in any module menu of the admin website.

I have two files : `admin/controller/module/rlsq_events.php` and  `catalog/controller/module/rlsq_events.php`

`admin/controller/module/rlsq_events.php` includes the `install()` and `uninstall()` methods as well as two admin-based events' functions (for `pre.admin.store.delete` and `post.admin.store.backup`)

`catalog/controller/module/rlsq_events.php` includes one other event handling function (for `post.moneris.order.add` which is a custom event which I trigger in another of my modules, which works perfectly).

Now, I really need to know where/how to call the `install()` function for this event handling module.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem myself. It turns out, if you have a file with the same name in both `admin/controller/module/` and `admin/controller/extension/module/` it will not load the install method.

It will still allow you to install and enable your extension, but the install and uninstall methods will not load. Strange behavior. Maybe somebody knows why?

Answer (score 1):

The `install()` function is called when you are installing your module. In `admin/controller/module`  there is a line of code for the `install()` function.

```
// Call install method if it exsits
$this->load->controller('module/' . $this->request->get['extension'] . '/install');
```

And in this `install()` method, you have to perform some action required for your module. Like setting user permission, add new tables etc.

Comment: But then, it goes back to what I said : My module doesn't appear in the module list of the admin website. (which I could then simply click "Install" to call the said `install()` method) What exactly do you think would be needed for the admin controller file to be considered a module?

Comment: Have you checked your module's key or some id is saved in `setting` table?  If you put your `controller file` and `language file` in your admin folder's `module directory` then opencart will consider it as a module and will list it in module list.

Comment: If not any setting saved then check `extension` table. The `code` in extension table is the module's controller file's name

Comment: I indeed had to do the whole Admin settings page chabang with the language files and the view for it to show it in the modules list. Your answer wasn't quite "it" but it helped the breakthrough. Thanks.